# Remote desktop or VNC into Kubuntu 14.10 from windows

Tags: kubuntu, vnc, rdp

I've had another post on here dealing with beta version/realvnc, I've since started over and am using Kubuntu 14.10 with KDE plasma (the gold release).

At this point I'm looking for any solution to remote desktop or VNC from my windows 8.1 to Kubuntu 14.10 with KDE plasma (not version 5, its the KDE 4.1 I believe, whatever comes with final release of 14.10)

any suggestions on an RDP or VNC which will work?
thanks AJ

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, with KDE, you can use xrdp package which will allow you to remote connect to your ubuntu or kubuntu system.

You can find detailed instructions over [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=6717)

The steps are guide straight forward

Install xrdp on your kubuntu system using

- **sudo apt-get install xrdp**

Tell your system to use kde desktop using this command line

- **echo startkde >~/.xsession**

Restart xrdp and give it a try

Note that by default, the xrdp login page will use the English US Keyboard layout

Till next time
See ya

Answer (score 1):

You can install/use **`xrdp`** package to do the needful. running this will allow the machine to remote desktop the machine from any where.

Comment: I've tried all of the below, same results , the client won't refresh.  Mouse works but the client shows an old screen and flickers.

ReanVNC
TightVNC
x11VNC
kfrd

I have installed xrdp but have not been able to connect to it. On the client (windows) side I've tried RealVNC and tightVNC

Any suggestions?
Thanks AJ